# Carousel effect for Vertical scrolling UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel, uicollectionviewflowlayout

How to achieve Carousel Effect for a vertically scrolling `UICollectionView`? For example, we have 10 `UICollectionViewCell`s aligned vertically in `UICollectionView`, assume if we are seeing the the 5th `UICollectionViewCell`, then 4th and 6th `UICollectionViewCell`s are to be behind this 5th `UICollectionViewCell` with some part of 4th is visible on top and some part of 6th visible on bottom along with some scaling. You can check the images down there for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

I tried many libraries from `github`, but I can't find the exact solution.Please help me to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/canopas/CardsLayout

Comment: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView

Comment: Just modify library according to your need